# Find Distinct Values & then Group by and count in mySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

I have a table which has some duplicate values for the same date

```
MyTime   |  Mrc  |  Num
21-Dec   |  ABC  |  200
21-Dec   |  ABC  |  200
20-Dec   |  DEF  |  300
20-Dec   |  DEF  |  300
19-Dec   |  XYZ  |  254
21-Nov   |  ABC  |  200
```

I want to ignore the duplicate entries and group by the `DATE(Mytime), Mrc, Num` i.e. I want to detect entries which have same day of the month, Mrc & Num appearing more than once but are not exact duplicate

So the expected output is:

```
MyTime |  Mrc  |  Num  | cnt
21     |  ABC  |  200  |  2
```

I tried something along the following lines:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(MyTime, Mrc, Num, Count(*) as cnt)
FROM  `My_Table`
WHERE MType != 'XX'
AND HType != 'YY'
GROUP BY Date(MyTime), Mrc, Num
ORDER BY MyTime DESC
```

But it is not working.

Comment: So if I understand you right you want just get count of records with same date?

Comment: And what do if there are records with same date but with different values in other columns?

Comment: Yes, count of records with same date (not month), same Mrc & same Num, But ignoring those entries which are exact duplicate. Above the expected result is 21 (because same Mrc (ABC) and same Num(200) appearing twice - Dec & Nov)

Comment: What's your primary key?

Comment: @Strawberry primary key is an 'ID' column (not shown above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `COUNT(DISTINCT MyTime)`:

```
SELECT
    DAY(MyTime) as MyTime
    Mrc,
    Num,
    COUNT(DISTINCT MyTime) as cnt
FROM  `My_Table`
WHERE MType != 'XX'
AND HType != 'YY'
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Notes:

- You want the `DAY()` function, not the `DATE()` function to extract the day part of the date
- `DISTINCT` is a *keyword*, not a function, so avoid using brackets ie use it like this: `SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2, ...`
- `COUNT(DISTINCT expression)` returns the number of *different* values

Comment: Thank you, it works as expected. Btw, it is possible that I select complete Mytime but use only DAY while doing Group By

Comment: What do you mean exactly? What would be the output you would want given your sample data?

Comment: I understand it would not mean anything because the returned month would be ambiguous but I was hoping it would return the most latest month of occurrence. The expected output is 21-Dec in Mytime instead of just 21